# Unable to create a new project in the Google Developer Console

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm unable to create a new project in the Google Developer Console. I have a single project there but any attempts to add a new one returns a **Forbidden** error message in the Activities log window (see https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpGI3.png).

I've tried different project names and changed the data location from US to EU but nothing is working.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you edit your question and post the exact error you are getting?

Comment: I've adjusted the question and also included a link to a picture of the error message.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've had the same problem and after a day of hitting my head against it I figured it out.

Basically you need to enable 'Google Developers Console' in the apps section of Google Admin.

1. Go to admin.google.com
2. Go to Apps
3. Go to Additional Google Services
4. Go To Google Developers Console:
   [image]
5. Make sure that that the developers console is enabled for the organisation who is getting the forbidden error message.

Note: If you have to enable it for an organisation or everyone this change can take upto 24 Hours. For me it took about 10 minutes to take effect.

Comment: Forbidden isn't a very helpful error message.. Great answer @Lofty

Comment: Took effect instantly for us. Thanks for saving us the time figuring this one out.

Comment: This saved the day for me - took 30mins to activate. The error I got was `generic::FAILED_PRECONDITION: ;AppErrorCode=9`